# Can OpenVZ templates be used for KVM?

Tags: vps, kvm, openvz

Chatting with the Hostens hosting provider I was told that for their `KVM VPS` they use `OpenVZ` [templates](https://wiki.openvz.org/Download/template/precreated). I wonder if this is a common practice or whether `KVM` should have its own templates.

For a totally inexperienced point of view, since they offer standard `VPS` with `OpenVZ` and `KVM VPS`, my question is if in the end their `KVM VPS` using `OpenVZ` templates might be not so different in performance from their standard `VPS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenVZ 6 templates can't be used on KVM servers and they are not used at Hostens. Sorry for our specialist mistake. KVM VPS have their own templates.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Are you using your own templates or third-party templates?

Comment: Using our own templates. Have to make sure of security and stability.